# Adapt React.createClass method to ES6 Class Component with react-data-grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working the [react-data-grid](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid) library to create an filterable datatable in react. All of their examples use the depreciated `React.createClass` method, and I am trying to refactor to the ES6 Class Components.

Specifically, I am trying to refactor the Filterable Grid example:

- [demo](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/filterable-grid)
- [source](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/scripts/example09-filterable-grid.js)
- [gist of non-refactored adaption that is working](https://gist.github.com/pcooney10/18c448eec5b8426f9236a3d4a2760e02)

My refactored code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDataGrid from 'react-data-grid'
const { Toolbar, Data: { Selectors } } = require('react-data-grid-addons')

class FilterableTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this._columns = [
      {
        key: 'id',
        name: 'ID',
        width: 80
      },
      {
        key: 'task',
        name: 'Title',
        editable: true
      },
      {
        key: 'priority',
        name: 'Priority',
        editable: true
      },
      {
        key: 'issueType',
        name: 'Issue Type',
        editable: true
      },
      {
        key: 'complete',
        name: '% Complete',
        editable: true
      },
      {
        key: 'startDate',
        name: 'Start Date',
        editable: true
      },
      {
        key: 'completeDate',
        name: 'Expected Complete',
        editable: true
      }
    ];

    this.state = { rows: this.createRows(1001), filters: {} };
    console.log(this.state);
  }


  getRandomDate = (start, end) => {
    return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime())).toLocaleDateString();
  }

  createRows = () => {
    let rows = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
      rows.push({
        id: i,
        task: 'Task ' + i,
        complete: Math.min(100, Math.round(Math.random() * 110)),
        priority: ['Critical', 'High', 'Medium', 'Low'][Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1)],
        issueType: ['Bug', 'Improvement', 'Epic', 'Story'][Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1)],
        startDate: this.getRandomDate(new Date(2015, 3, 1), new Date()),
        completeDate: this.getRandomDate(new Date(), new Date(2016, 0, 1))
      });
    }

    return rows;
  }

  getRows = () => {
    return Selectors.getRows(this.state);
  }

  getSize = () => {
    return this.getRows().length;
  }

  rowGetter = ( rowIdx ) => {
    let rows = this.getRows();
    return rows[rowIdx];
  }

  handleFilterChange = ({ filter }) => {
    let newFilters = Object.assign({}, this.state.filters);
    if (filter.filterTerm) {
      newFilters[filter.column.key] = filter;
    } else {
      delete newFilters[filter.column.key];
    }
    this.setState({ filters: newFilters });
  }

  onClearFilters = () => {
    // all filters removed
    this.setState({filters: {} });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ReactDataGrid
        columns={this._columns}
        rowGetter={this.rowGetter}
        enableCellSelect={true}
        rowsCount={this.getSize()}
        minHeight={800}
        toolbar={<Toolbar enableFilter={true}/>}
        onAddFilter={this.handleFilterChange}
        onClearFilters={this.onClearFilters} />);
  }

}

export default FilterableTable
```

**Issue:**

An issue arises when I click the filter button - a new header row is rendered (via the Toolbar component), but there is no input field. This screenshot shows the two examples side by side - my ES6 version on top and the createClass version on the bottom:
[image: screenshot comparison]

I am not sure what is causing this, but have a feeling it might be due to the way I am importing `Toolbar` ? Any help or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated ! (As well as any other suggestions re refactoring this component.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable filtering for a given column, you need to set filterable=true for that column. So, add filterable:true to each object in this._columns. For more info, check http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/filterable-grid.

```
this._columns = [
  {
    key: 'id',
    name: 'ID',
    width: 80
  },
  {
    key: 'task',
    name: 'Title',
    editable: true,
    filterable:true
  },
  {
    key: 'priority',
    name: 'Priority',
    editable: true,
    filterable:true
  },
  {
    key: 'issueType',
    name: 'Issue Type',
    editable: true,
    filterable:true
  },
  {
    key: 'complete',
    name: '% Complete',
    editable: true,
    filterable:true
  },
  {
    key: 'startDate',
    name: 'Start Date',
    editable: true,
    filterable:true
  },
  {
    key: 'completeDate',
    name: 'Expected Complete',
    editable: true,
    filterable:true
  }
];
```

Comment: Yikes. Can't believe I missed that in my example, but appreciate the help

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help

Comment: Indeed. I am glad as well. Sometimes the answers as so obvious... that you can't even see them... lol